# Pandas 0.22.0: IndexError: list index out of range when reading xls

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.6

I'm trying to load a 282Mb (65536 rows x 138 columns) .xls file into a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filename = r'invoicing.xls'
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
excelFile = os.path.join(dir, filename)
invoicing_info = pd.read_excel(excelFile)
```

But I'm getting this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 698, in put_cell_unragged
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx] = ctype
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juanda/PycharmProjects/Hyperion_info/load_info.py", line 11, in <module>
    invoicing_info = pd.read_excel(excelFile, sheet_name=0)
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 162, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 107, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.fake_globals_get_sheet()
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 728, in fake_globals_get_sheet
    self.get_sheets()
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 719, in get_sheets
    self.get_sheet(sheetno)
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 710, in get_sheet
    sh.read(self)
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 1361, in read
    self_put_cell(rowx, colx, None, d, self.fixed_BIFF2_xfindex(cell_attr, rowx, colx))
  File "/Users/juanda/conda_envs/Hyperion_contracts_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 709, in put_cell_unragged
    assert 1 <= nr <= self.utter_max_rows
AssertionError
```

I think this is a problem with the .xls extension but I can't modify the file before uploading it. How can I upload this .xls file in a reliable manner?

Comment: @bernie The sheet names can be declared as integers according to its zero-indexed position https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html. I removed the argument but still getting the same error.

Comment: Probably caused by Excel can only handle one million rows at a time.

Comment: the excel file has 65536 rows x 138 columns @Sphinx

Comment: Probably you can try read partial rows instead of entire file like this (only read first 100 rows): workbook = pd.ExcelFile(excelFile); rows = workbook.book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows; workbook_dataframe = pd.read_excel(excelFile, skip_footer = (rows - 100- 1))

Comment: Check this [xlrd issues:ragged_rows](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/168),

Comment: What version of xlrd are you using?

Comment: @djk47463 xlrd V1.1.0

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data that can be saved as a `.xls` file that produces this error? I am running the same configuration, and cannot reproduce this error.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. After i copied and pasted "values only" into a new sheet, move the sheet around (order of the sheet), it is working now. This is annoying.

Answer (score -1):

Move copy of all sheets in new excel and save with same name. It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).